# Strawberry leaves

Tags: modeling

I would like to model a strawberry:

[image]

However, I don't know how to model the leaves on top. I already made the basic shape: [image]

Comment: This shouldn't be asked as a one question. Please use edit button and make this one about seeds OR leaves. You can ask as much questions as you want. Please also be more descriptive in your questions.

Comment: Also check here: https://www.blendernation.com/2017/04/09/behind-scenes-strawberry/

Comment: @LukeD Okay, I'll do so. Thanks a lot for the link!

Comment: The leaves in that linked tutorial are quite different from your reference, I would try to model (and texture) a flat shape like real leaves above, then maybe deform them using curve modifiers...? You could also use planes textured with alpha (transparency) images, to get simpler geometry. There are many questions here about modeling leaves, usually LOTS of leaves...